# What's the problem in this regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var regex = /^[a-z\-A-Z_0-9]{1,}\u0040[_\-0-9a-zA-Z]{1,65}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
document.write(regex.check("hi@email.com"));
```

Comment: Doesn't have to be in JS. @DarkLight What is the problem, what doesn't work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression for validating email addresses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

Comment: That regex will break for a good amount of email addresses, better to find one that is already written.

Comment: There's no "check()" method for RegExp instances, at least not in all browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't output anything, becase the check method doesn't exist in RegExp. You should use [RegExp.test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method

Answer (score 3):

`.{0,0}` does not match anything (i.e. you probably want to start with `^` and end with `$`). And you do not allow `jon.bob.smith@my.domain.museum`. You should probably read the [stackoverflow question about the best email regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses).

Comment: to confirm this you can plug the regex in at regexpal.com and play around with the results.